# Plotting 3 points per data set in lollipop-type chart

Tags: r, data-visualization, dataset, excel

I am wanting to plot a graph where I have multiple data points per category of data. For some context, I have done some analysis on different samples and now have up to 3 3 data points for each sample and I am wanting to present them in a lollipop chart-type way (see image). I'm wondering if this is possible to plot in excel, and if not, what is the easiest way to plot data in this way?

It would also be helpful if I could have 2 of these 'lines' of 3 data points (e.g. different colours) for each sample to present different values I'm extracting from the data of each.

Thanks,
Charllotte

[image]

Comment: Have you considered a dumbbell plot and a scatterplot for the middle dots?  https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-dot-plot-charts

Comment: Advice on using particular software appears off-topic here.

Comment: Hi Charllotte. As Nick Cox said, you won't get advice here about particular software (even though you could ask questions on whether your visualization is a good idea, if other visualizations would be better, etc.). I'd suggest you to ask your question on https://superuser.com/ for advice on how to use Excel to create the visualization you have in mind, or on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ if you're looking for an alternative to Excel to do that.

Comment: Because Excel will plot line segments and point symbols, you can plot literally anything you want in Excel.  (I posted an example at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/54583/919.)  It's a matter of how hard you're willing to work to do it ;-).