# Should I use the use the confidence-t or confidence-norm function in Excel?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation

- n=6 (this relates to maximum values of measurements of force (in Newton) when conducting the same process with the same setting of parameters 6 times)
- [There is `CONFIDENCE.NORM` in Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/confidence-norm-function-HP010335675.aspx)
- [and `CONFIDENCE.T`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/confidence-t-function-HA010345277.aspx).

When I refer to all these 6 values, I am using [STDEVP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/stdev-p-function-HP010335772.aspx) (or whatever exactly it is called in the English version of Excel--I got various hits for the "whole" stdev variant).

1. What should I use for calculating a CI with `\alpha = 0.05` then, `CONFIDENCE.NORM` or `CONFIDENCE.T`?
2. If I refer to 4 of said 6 values and then use `STDEV.S`, would that be correct? Also, if I like to calculate the CI (alpha=0.05) for those 4 values, I have to switch the formula to using the stdev.s value, right?

Comment: Can you edit your question (use the "edit" link at lower left) to say what kind of data you have (i.e what kinds of values your data take)?

Comment: @Alexis Edited the op. Is that ok?

Comment: The proper answer is "no."  Frankly, I wouldn't trust Excel's builtin functions, having read too many careful analyses showing that some of them produce incorrect (albeit usually in the 4th or 5th place) results.

Comment: That's a safe default position, @Carl, but not everybody has the luxury of adopting it.  For subtler and more constructive criticism of Excel (and other spreadsheets) consider our thread on [Excel as a statistics workbench](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3392/excel-as-a-statistics-workbench).

Comment: @whuber True 'dat :-( .  I plead guilty to being a minor-league evangelist, attempting to bring the "news" to  folks  that there are far better alternatives to Excel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For continuous measurements, such as force in Newtons, where you do not know the *population* variance (as opposed to sample variance, which is what you have to work with – implying `STDEV.S`), the confidence interval of the mean based on the *t* distribution is what you are after.

You would use the confidence interval based on the normal distribution only if you had the population variance *a priori*.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look at the documentation, you should be using `CONFIDENCE.T` since you are estimating the standard deviation of your sample.

For `CONFIDENCE.NORM`, the standard deviation must be known (aka not *estimated* from your data).

Finally, you should be using `STDEV.S` for all calculations.