# Does the wild bootstrap use residuals or standardised residuals

Tags: standard-deviation, bootstrap, standardization

I have seen a few sources that describe the wild bootstrap as so:

> For each bootstrap instance, compute a new $y$ based on:
>
> $y^*_i = \hat{y}_i+\hat{\epsilon}_iv_i$
>
> Where $y^*_i$ is the $i^{th}$ bootstrap instance, $\hat{y}_i$ is the original data, $\hat{\epsilon}_i$ is the residual and $v_i$ is a bootstrap variable with mean zero variance one.

One example would be the wikipedia page on bootstrapping for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#:%7E:text=identity%20matrix.-,Wild%20bootstrap,based%20on%20the%20residuals%20values.).

However, I've seen other sources saying that the wild bootstrap instead uses the standardised residuals like so:

> For each bootstrap instance, compute a new $y$ based on:
>
> $y^*_i = \hat{y}_i+\frac{\hat{\epsilon}_i}{\sigma}v_i$
>
> Where $y^*_i$ is the $i^{th}$ bootstrap instance, $\hat{y}_i$ is the original data, $\hat{\epsilon}_i$ is the residual, $v_i$ is a bootstrap variable with mean zero variance one and $\sigma$ is the estimated standard deviation of the $y_i$ variables.

An example of this would be the Wu 1986 paper [here](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/135473/Kybernetika_38-2002-4_1.pdf).

Which of these is correct? I don't understand the logic behind using the standardised residuals here.

Answer (score 1):

The article you have linked for the formula where the residual is divided by sigma is not the original paper from Wu (1986), but instead the link leads to a paper from Prášková (2002) called "Bootstrap in nonstationary autoregression", so I don't know where you found the information about the residual being "standardized". Further, this formula does not really depict a standardized residual, since the standardized residual is the original residual divided by the estimated standard error of the residuals not the estimated standard deviation of y (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/166539/396429)).

In Wu's original [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2241454?seq=22) (p. 1282) he describes the *i*th unstandardized residual being transformed (divided by the square root of 1 minus the *i*th leverage value)and multiplied by a bootstrap variable t* (or v*). Variations of this version of the wild bootstrap can be found in e.g. [MacKinnon (2011)](https://www.econstor.eu/handle/10419/67778), or [Cribari-Neto (2004)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947302003663). In other iterations of the wild bootstrap, f.i. the one implemented in SPSS, the residual is not transformed prior to multiplying it with the bootstrap variable t*, but it is again the unstandardized residual that is used.

I personally would not think it correct to use standardized residuals, since the goal of each bootstrap iteration is to compute a vector of bootstrapped y-values with which the unstandardized regression coefficients can be computed. This would require the y-values (and thus the residuals) to remain in their original metric.

Comment: The argument for standardising them is that they are then more nearly exchangeable; it might well be better to rescale them to the original variance afterwards, for the reason you give.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Do you by any chance have any literature that discusses this, since I have not come upon using standardised residuals in the context of the wild bootstrap?

Comment: I'm going off memories from last century, so no, sorry.